# Handling null conditions for setter action in a better way

Tags: java, getter-setter, null-check

Before a DB call, i am setting some data from a map into an object using its setter methods for DB update call. Now the map may not have some data.

So what i want to know is that instead of adding code to check null for each field before adding data to the object, is there any better ways to do this by reducing the number of IF for checking null values before calling setter methods.

I have conditions like below right now

```
if(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE1_VALUE) != null){
  object.setAttribute1Value(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE1_VALUE));
}
if(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE2_VALUE) != null){
  object.setAttribute2Value(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE2_VALUE));
}
if(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE3_VALUE) != null){
  object.setAttribute3Value(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE3_VALUE));
}
if(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE4_VALUE) != null){
  object.setAttribute4Value(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE4_VALUE));
}
if(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE5_VALUE) != null){
  object.setAttribute5Value(valueMap.get(ATTRIBUTE5_VALUE));
}
```

One way is obviously using Reflection but i want to know if there is any other ways also to do this.

Comment: please show your current code

Comment: Why are you checking for null before setting the value? Are the instance variables in the class that contains these setters primitive types? If yes, why not change them to wrapper types. object.setXxx(null) is anyway going to have no effect so why check for null? Why not just call the setters straight away?

Comment: actually i am setting these values to perform DB update. I have fetched an entity object using hibernate and i need to update the incoming data to DB. object.setXXX(null) will not give an exception but that will update that field to NULL in database, which i don't want. So checking null is trivial here for any field which is not there in the map.

Comment: which  version of Java do you use?

Comment: with Java 8, it would be straight indeed.

Comment: Yup, but i need to use Java7 only. No upgradations from client for now :( . Is there any better solution for this in Java 7? Reflection can be a solution though as my key values are the same as the property in domain so i can opt for Reflection as well

Answer (score 0):

Note you do the `get(ATTRIBUTE1_VALUE)` call twice for each branch.

Instead just do `containsKey(ATTRIBUTE1_VALUE)` in the `if` check.

If the logic to populate `valueMap` isn't adding null for keys this is fine.

*Identify where nulls could originate and stop it there, instead of having to handle it further down the stack like what is happening here.

Comment: Yes, thats a better way to handle that. But i'll still have to call containsKey for each property in the object right. Won't that increase the complexity of the class abnormally? Or i it OK to have containsKey check for each property that i need to update?

Comment: If you want to null check you need an additional check somehow either by !=null, contains, using java8 optional. If you want to remove the complexity then you should make sure whatever populates the map does so correctly, writes default values if nothing is found in the DB etc